# vb.net linq query for multiple informations

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a datatable treno1  containing 10 columns about group railway reservation. I need to know some information : from a city per wagon all destinations
I get a json reservation from a web.

```
With treno1
    .Columns.Add("Departure", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Arrival", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("PNR", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Level", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Last Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Car", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("seat", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("first name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Train", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("ID res", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
End With


    For Each item As JProperty In data
        item.CreateReader()
    
        For Each msg As JObject In item.Values
            treno1.Rows.Add(msg("departureLocationName"), msg("arrivalLocationName"), msg("pnrCode"), msg("serviceLevel"), msg("lastName"), msg("wagon"), msg("seat"), msg("firstName"), msg("transportMeanName"), msg("Id"))
        Next
    Next`
```

here i got some info

```
Dim destinations = From n In table1.AsEnumerable()
                           Where n.Field(Of String)("Departure") = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
                           Select n.Field(Of String)("Arrival")


Dim wagons = From n In table1.AsEnumerable()
                       Where n.Field(Of String)("Departure") = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
                       Select n.Field(Of String)("wagon")


Dim wagonlist = (wagons.Distinct).ToList
Dim destinations = (destination.Distinct).ToList
```

NOW to get : wagon number-destinations and people for that destinations how could be the query ?
for instance : From Rome (combobox1.selectevalue)
wagon 1 - 10 people boarding- 5 Florence,3 bologna-2 Milan
wagon 2 - 14 people boarding- 5 Florence,3 bologna-2 Milan,4 Piacenza
etc...
how could be the query

i made this one but it doesnt make the right output.

```
    For Each value In wagonlist
        Dim destinazioneglobale = From n In treno1.AsEnumerable()
                                          Where n.Field(Of String)("Departure") = ComboBox1.SelectedValue And n.Field(Of String)("Wagon") = value
                                          Select n.Field(Of String)("Arrival")
    
For Each element In destinazioneglobale
    Dim count4 = treno1.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(row) (row.Field(Of String)("Departure") = ComboBox1.SelectedValue) And (row.Field(Of String)("Arrival") = element))
    ListBox11.Items.Add(value.ToString & (element.ToString))
    Next
            Next
```

Comment: any idea for the solution ?

Comment: What is a wagon? Is it a car? A train? I don't see any "wagon" in your field list.